# Convert simple data.table to named vector

Tags: r, data.table

I need to convert simple `data.table` to named vector.

Lets say I have data.table

```
a <- data.table(v1 = c('a', 'b', 'c'), v2 = c(1,2,3))
```

and I want to get the following named vector

```
b <- c(1, 2, 3)
names(b) <-  c('a', 'b', 'c')
```

Is there a way to do it simple

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `setNames()` in `j`:

```
a[, setNames(v2, v1)]
# a b c 
# 1 2 3
```

Comment: ah beat me by 30 seconds

Comment: @MichaelChirico :), btw. is it called `J` or `j`?

Comment: it's `j`; `J` is actually shorthand for the "`J`oin" function that's available in `i`; see ?J

Comment: works faster than Ronak Shah answer

Comment: @user2761282 if speed is very important this should be a bit faster: `setNames(a[["v2"]], a[["v1"]])`

Answer (score 0):

We can use `split` and `unlist` to get it as named vector.

```
unlist(split(a$v2, a$v1))
#a b c 
#1 2 3
```

Comment: works but a bit slower than the other option